# Why do alternate web browsers want access to "Chrome Safe Storage" in my Keychain?

Tags: macos, security, web-browser

When launching some alternate Mac web browsers such as [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com), I get a message asking me:

> Vivaldi wants to use your confidential information stored in “Chrome Safe Storage” in your keychain.
>
> Do you want to allow access to this item?
>
> [Always Allow]  [Deny]  [Allow]

[image]

- What information is stored there?
- What are the benefits of "Allow"?
- What are the penalties for "Deny"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a couple of things going on here:

- **Vivaldi** - In terms of Vivaldi this is something that's been happening for at least a couple of years, although it's not always triggered. You may want to read [What is the Chrome Safe Storage](https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/2385/what-is-the-chrome-safe-storage/6) discussion at Vivaldi's forums.
- **More generally** - There seems to be an issue recently where a number of apps are requesting access to Chrome Safe Storage. It's not just happening with browsers, but other apps too. I first noticed this in mid-July on an iMac running a 3rd party video downloader/converter. I'm not sure what changed, but some of these app developers have had to issue updates to remove this behaviour.

In terms of the info that's stored there - it's basically a secure location to store credentials such as passwords for sites you visit.

The advantages and disadvantages will differ depending on the app:

- in the case of browsers it will mean things like having to manually log in to sites you want to visit. Obviously the benefit is not having to do this.
- in the case of other apps (such as the video downloader/converter I mention above), the user whose iMac had this issue could only convert videos, but not download them. (**Note:** In their case an update fixed this).

**Further reading**

The following *may* be of interest:

- [Google Chrome wants to use your confidential information stored in...your keychain](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/td93NVk3q2E)
- [Bug 178358 - A pop up message "Google Chrome wants to use your confidential information stored in your keychain"](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178358)